# Who are humans' closest relatives, after primates?

Tags: zoology, homework, phylogenetics

This question [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/what-is-the-closest-species-to-humans-in-animal-kingdom) addresses the controversy of whether humans are more closely related to bonobos or chimps.

My question is - which group of animals are are closest relatives, beyond primates? Or which group of animals are all primates most closely related to?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Short answer**

It is a [flying lemur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colugo) (there exist only 2 species). Flying lemurs and primates are together a sister clade to [treeshrews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treeshrew).

**Easy source of information**

Have a look at the post [The best free and most up to date phylogenetic tree on the internet?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/the-best-free-and-most-up-to-date-phylogenetic-tree-on-the-internet).

In short, you can have a look at [onezoom.org](http://onezoom.org/), [tolweb.org](http://tolweb.org/Eutheria/15997) or [opentreeoflife.org](https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/opentree/argus/opentree8.0@ott93302) by yourself!

**Tree of life of placental mammals**

Here is a screenshot coming from tolweb.org.

[image]

In this tree, there are polytomies showing everything that is unknown. This tree was last updated in 1995 and there are also clades that we now know were misplaced including the bats (as commented by @NoahSnyder). It is not handy to make a good screenshot from onezoom.org or opentreeoflife.org so I just welcome you to explore the tree of life by yourself on [onezoom.org](http://onezoom.org/) or [opentreeoflife.org](https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/opentree/argus/ottol@244265/Mammalia) to get a better representation of the reality.

**Tree of Supraprimates**

[Supraprimates (=*Euarchontoglires*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euarchontoglires) include all primates and a few of the most related clades. Stealing the tree from @Gwenn's answer, here is the tree of Supraprimates

[[image]

Here is the original tree from [Janecka et al. (2007)](http://www.bx.psu.edu/miller_lab/dist/flying_lemur.pdf)

[image]

Here we see that flying lemurs (=*Dermoptera*) is a sister clade of primates (ignoring the extinct [*plesiadapiformes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plesiadapiformes)) and treeshrews (=*Scandentia*) are a sister clade of flying lemurs and primates together. Below I briefly talk about these three clades and about their position on the phylogenetic tree.

**Flying lemurs**

Flying lemurs is a small clade that contains only two extant species, both found in the family of [colugos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colugo). Note that flying lemurs are not [lemurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemur) (which is confusing). Here is what a flying lemur look like

[image]

The position of flying lemurs on the phylogenetic tree has always been quite uncertain. In the tolweb.org screenshot above, flying lemurs (=*Dermoptera*) is a sister clade to bats (=*Chiroptera*) and together they are sister clade to treeshrews and primates. However, [Janecka et al. (2007)](http://www.bx.psu.edu/miller_lab/dist/flying_lemur.pdf) placed flying lemurs as the sister clade to primates. Together flying lemurs and primates are a sister clade to tree shrews.

**Tree shrews**

[Treeshrews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treeshrew) is a clade of 20 species native from southeast Asia. Before, the era of phylogenetic comparisons, treeshrews were mistakenly thought to be part of the *Insectivora*.

[image]

**Extinct clade of Plesiadapiforms**

Although they are represented above as a sister clade of primates, it is possible that they the fossil we found are just individuals coming from the lineage giving rise to primates. As such, they would not be a clade aside from primates. Below is an artistic representation of what they may have looked like.

[image]

**Introduction on phylogenetic trees**

As the question is quite introductory, I presume you might want to improve your understanding of phylogenetic trees. You might want to make sure, you understand what a monophyletic group (=clade) is and understand why a chimpanzee and a human are both equally related to any species of treeshrews.

Here are two sources of information for you:

- [Understanding Evolution (UC Berkeley) > The history of life](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/0_0_0/evo_03)
- [This answer on Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52700/why-do-the-ancestors-of-birds-still-exist/52729#52729)

Answer (score 24):

The most closely related animals to primates are [colugos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colugo) (order Dermoptera).

The next most closely related after colugos are [tree shrews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treeshrew) (order Scandentia).

The next most closely related after tree shrews are [rodents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treeshrew) (order Rodentia) and [lagomorphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagomorpha) (order Lagomorpha) (rabbits, hares, and pikas).

[image]

Sources: [Wikipedia's section on the evolutionary history of primates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primate#Evolutionary_history) and [onezoom.org](http://onezoom.org).

Comment: Where did you see that *Dermoptera* is sister clade to primates? Do you have a reference for that? Note that colugo is a family made of two extant species only. This family is nested within *Dermoptera* and therefore a colugo is equally related to any primate than any other *dermoptera*

Comment: @Remi.b Just [Wikipedia's section on the evolutionary history of primates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primate#Evolutionary_history). Wikipedia in turn cites [this *Science* article from 2007](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/318/5851/792.full) (which I sadly cannot read to verify because I don't have a subscription). And from what I understand, colugos are the *only* extant members of Dermoptera.

Comment: @Remi.b: The position of colugos (*Dermoptera*) in the evolutionary tree has traditionally been somewhat uncertain, but recent studies (such as the 2007 *Science* article by Janečka *et al.* mentioned by Gwenn, [PDF here](http://www.bx.psu.edu/miller_lab/dist/flying_lemur.pdf)) do apparently support their position as the closest surviving sister clade to the primates.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that *Dermoptera* are also called flying lemur (which is a confusing term)! As a consequence, it is not so much an issue of definition as I suggested rather than an uncertainty about the position of flying lemurs on the tree. I will update my answer. Thanks for your help. +1 on answer and comments!