# The best free and most up to date phylogenetic tree on the internet?

Tags: phylogenetics, database

I found phylogenetic tree in wikipedia is lacks of accuracy. It actually confusing with versions. Some terms was not scientifically accurate with dna analysis anymore

So are there anyone know where is the most updated datasource on the internet?

Comment: Tree of what organisms?

Comment: @kmm All if possible. Vertebrate, Arthropod and Mollusc is most interested in

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Available ressources**

I would recommend [oneZoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/) is probably the best ressource. [oneZoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/) is based on [openTreeOfLife.org](https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/) (for phylogenetic relationships) and [eol.org (Encyclopedia Of Life)](http://eol.org/) (mainly for the pictures I think). If you do not fancy to much the display and links of oneZoom/org, then I would just recommend [openTreeOfLife.org](https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/).

There is also [tolweb.org](http://tolweb.org) but it is not as nicely updated as [openTreeOfLife.org](https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/) (and therefore [openTreeOfLife.org](https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/)) and the dates are harder to find.

**Particularities of oneZoom.org**

I particularly like that for each node [oneZoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/) offers links to

- wikipedia
- encyclopedia of life
- the red list
- NCBI

, which makes it a very appreciable tool. [oneZoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/) has the advantage of a nice display (although a bit slow to load IMO) and is easy to navigate and get time to the [Most Recent Common Ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_recent_common_ancestor) of a lineage.

I also like that you can just add the species name after "#" in the URL and it will jump to its node. [Here is the Kagu](http://www.onezoom.org/life.html/@=86672?vis=spiral#Kagu) for example.

**Potential issues in oneZoom.org**

Of course, [oneZoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/) contain a few mistakes! Some of them are unintentional (wrong picture, misrepresentation of what is known from the literature, fail to update information), some of them are caused by lack of knowledge of true phylogenetic relationships. [oneZoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/) does not say how certain we are that a given speciation event is correct or correctly dated, it just display the best estimates we have. If a specific node is of interest to you, you will need to go to the scientific literature which will give you much more information about what we know and what we roughly guess.

Answer (score 2):

[Open Tree of Life](https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/opentree/argus/opentree7.0@ott93302) could be what you're after. It was updated last month [according to this page](https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/about/progress). The visual interface is rather bland, but that's probably the price one has to pay for accuracy and completeness.

Vertebrates, arthropods and molluscs are all available as categories in the taxon search bar on the home page.