# Online phylogenetic tree of human lineages

Tags: genetics, evolution, human-genetics, database, human-evolution

I am looking for a source of information about the diversity of human lineages and their relationships.

With a quick google search it is easy to find this type of tree

[image]

A perfect online resource would...

- Contain a lot of lineages going to the most detailed lineages
- Contain links to wikipedia or other source of information that could help someone to:

  - identify a group
  - have an overview of their culture
- Contain visualization of their current (or past) geographic range.
- Contain visualization of migration patterns
- As mtDNA and Y chromosome may typically show different story, it'd be great if the resource would differentiate these and highlights specific cases where the two tree differ.

**Can you recommend some online resources?**

A review paper with nice graphs would also be welcome.

---

Related:

- The post [The best free and most up to date phylogenetic tree on the internet?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/the-best-free-and-most-up-to-date-phylogenetic-tree-on-the-internet/52224#52224) recommend resources for visualizing the tree of life.
- [This webite](http://000024.org/religions_tree/) offers a pretty amazing tree of religions.

Comment: Note that the structure of the human evolutionary tree depends on the kind of markers that are considered, male and female lineages don't necessarily have the same history, so SNPs from the mtDNA and Y chromosome will tell a different history, at least when looking into the details.

Comment: @bli Good point! I forgot about it. Following your comment, I added a bullet point in my list of descriptions for a perfect ressource. Thank you

Comment: Great link about the Tree of Religions!

Comment: Such a "tree" actually also has gene flow across branches. Related: [Human migration by haplogroups](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/photo/human-migration/), [World map of Y-DNA haplogroups](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World_Map_of_Y-DNA_Haplogroups.png), [Early human migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_human_migrations), [Simplified interactive map](https://genographic.nationalgeographic.com/human-journey/), [Other](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=human+migration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Trees for haplogroups**

See

- https://www.eupedia.com/genetics/phylogenetic_trees_Y-DNA_haplogroups.shtml
- https://www.eupedia.com/genetics/
- focus on Europe: https://www.eupedia.com/europe/origins_haplogroups_europe.shtml

  - and many pages linked therein such as https://www.eupedia.com/europe/Haplogroup_J2_Y-DNA.shtml#subclades
- and so on.

More detailed for mtDNA (female lineage):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_mitochondrial_DNA_haplogroup

  - and many links therein

More detailed for the Y chromosome (male lineage):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Y-chromosome_DNA_haplogroup

  - and many links therein
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Y-chromosome_haplogroups_in_populations_of_the_world and links therein
- https://isogg.org/tree/index.html
  and the Google Sheets linked therein
- https://www.yfull.com/tree/

**"Trees" for populations**

Note that the trees are for genes/haplogroups, whereas such a "tree" for populations actually also has gene flow across branches. Imagine overlaying the tree for mtDNA (female lineage) with the slightly different tree for Y-DNA (male lineage).

**Geography of migration**

Migration and geographical distance played a key role in the emergence of distinct populations. See

- maps of migration by haplogroups: [Human migration by haplogroups](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/photo/human-migration/), [World map of Y-DNA haplogroups](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World_Map_of_Y-DNA_Haplogroups.png), [Early human migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_human_migrations), [Simplified interactive map](https://genographic.nationalgeographic.com/human-journey/), [And so on](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=human%20migration).
- maps of distribution of haplogroups: [mtDNA in Europe](https://www.eupedia.com/europe/maps_mtdna_haplogroups.shtml), [Y-DNA in Europe](https://www.eupedia.com/europe/maps_Y-DNA_haplogroups.shtml), many of the links listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Y-chromosome_DNA_haplogroup#Phylogenetic_structure), [and so on](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=distribution%20of%20haplogroups)

Also check out how theories about migration are changing. For example about mutation M174: [theory around the year 2010](https://cosmolearning.org/images/migration-patterns-of-early-humans-788/) vs. [theory since at least 2016](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/photo/human-migration/).

Comment: There are a lot of very good resources in your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have used this online tool it has many of the features you are looking for.

http://itol.embl.de/shared/ivica

You can see some example in this page.

Comment: How to use this website, where exactly are human lineages?