# How to find out the when we had a common ancestor with a particular animal

Tags: evolution, macroevolution

For example, Jordan Peterson claims that human and lobsters have a common ancestor X million year ago. I wonder, how does he know it?

I'd be so delighted to visit a website, where I could select two currently existing species and it'd show me how many years ago they had had a common ancestor. Does anything like this exist? Do we at least have a database, so I, as a web programmer, could create this kind of website?

Comment: This post will interest you: [The best free and most up to date phylogenetic tree on the internet?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/the-best-free-and-most-up-to-date-phylogenetic-tree-on-the-internet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TimeTree [http://www.timetree.org] is one site that allows you to look at times from divergence of various taxa. Their [FAQ](http://www.timetree.org/faqs) describes how they calculate the times by pointing to this paper: [Tree of Life Reveals Clock-Like Speciation and Diversification](http://www.hedgeslab.org/pubs/260.pdf), but in general they used standard molecular clock approaches. You ask about downloading their database: [they say](http://www.timetree.org/faqs#q8)

> The TimeTree Database data is currently not available for download. Methods for making these data available in the future are currently under discussion.