# Are bears related to dogs in a similar way to how cats are related to 'panthers'?

Tags: evolution, taxonomy, mammals

I've tried searching on Wikipedia but I couldn't find what family dogs belonged to. Ursidae is 'bears' and Canis is 'dogs' ; Panthera is big cats like:- tigers and jaguars is what I know.

Comment: You will be interested int he ressources from the post [The best free and most up to date phylogenetic tree on the internet?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/the-best-free-and-most-up-to-date-phylogenetic-tree-on-the-internet)

Answer (score 2):

No, because panthers **are** cats, but bears are **not** dogs. You can see their phylogeny in a figure from one of my papers here: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Most-likely-phylogram-derived-from-the-Bayesian-Analysis-ln-533753675-Numerals_fig1_6550244

As you can see, Bears are most closely related to pinneped (seals and sea lions), with dogs as sister to that group.